# Permutations with strictly increasing cycles

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find the number of elements of the symmetric group $S_N$ that when decomposed into cycles, have strictly increasing numbers within each cycle. For example for $S_3$, there are 5, only (1 3 2) is discarded. (1 4) ( 3 8 5) would also be discarded in $S_8$

I then need to find the asymptotics for large N.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the decomposition necessarily in *disjoint* cycles?

Comment: Yes this is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well then it comes to finding the number of partitions of set $\{1,\dots,n\}$. If $\mathcal P=\{P_1,\dots,P_k\}$ is such a partition then each $P_i$ corresponds with exactly one cycle $C_i$ having strictly increasing numbers. If e.g. $P_i=\{1,3,2\}$ then $C_i=(1,2,3)$. The cycles $C_i$ are disjoint and their product is the decomposition of such an element of $S_n$.

If this is correct then their number is [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Counting_partitions) $B_n$.

Comment: Thank you it is exactly what I was looking for, I had spent time looking at partitions and composition of numbers but not partitions of a set, which is the way to go.

Comment: In fact, this was simply a warm up for the precise question I want to ask. I now want to further restrict permutations in the following way:

Disallow any "intertwinement" between cycles. This is easiest expressed with examples

I want to disallow for example (13)(24)

However, I still want to allow for cycles to be completely insertable between two numbers of another cycle. For example, (1 5 7)(3 4) is allowed, but not (1 5 7)(3 6).

This will further restrict the number of allowed permutations in $S_N$, if you have any idea it would be greatly appreciated! thx

Comment: Maybe it can help to have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncrossing_partition). It deals with so-called non-crossing partitions. If it does not help you any further then it might be a good idea to pose a new question with a link to this question.